# PHP Getting data from mysql and then use it in different actions

Tags: php

So I want to get some data from mysql and use it to create some conditions. Here is my code, but it only shows the last record from mysql.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$name_system = $row['name'];
$value_system = $row['value'];
}

if($name_system=='website_register' AND $value_system==1)
    $register_system = 1;
    else
    $register_system = 0;

if($name_system=='website_offline' AND $value_system==1)
    $offline_system = 1;
    else
    $offline_system = 0;
```

Then if I'm trying to echo "$offline_system" or "$register_system" in another page, it dosen't show the true data.

Comment: Why would another page know of these two local variables you defined? How do you get to the other page? Do you redirect from this code you posted?

Comment: Try using the **PDO** add-on for the same task.

Comment: This code is in a page called "gloabl.php". I'm trying to show the result in index.php with this code: <?php 
 include("gloabl.php");
 echo ("Offline: $offline_system <br />"); 
 echo ("Register: $register_system");
?>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You closed the while loop after `$value_system`. This means all records will be fetched and stored in `$name_system` and `$value_system` but the loop will overwrite the previous variable so only the last record is stored in that variable.

This seems to be an incomplete code. What you can do is move that closing brace further down the end of the procedure you are expecting to do for each record.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$name_system = $row['name'];
$value_system = $row['value'];
} // you closed the WHILE loop here.

if($name_system=='website_register' AND $value_system==1)
    $register_system = 1;
    else
    $register_system = 0;

if($name_system=='website_offline' AND $value_system==1)
    $offline_system = 1;
    else
    $offline_system = 0;
```

I imagine your code to be something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system") or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

$name_system = $row['name'];
$value_system = $row['value'];


if($name_system=='website_register' AND $value_system==1)
    $register_system = 1;
    else
    $register_system = 0;

if($name_system=='website_offline' AND $value_system==1)
    $offline_system = 1;
    else
    $offline_system = 0;

 // my imagination i was talking about:
 if ($offline_system) echo 'The system is offline<br />';
 else echo 'The system is online<br />';
 if ($register_system) echo 'The registration is online<br />';
 else echo 'The registration system is offline';

 } // curly brace MOVED.
```

Comment: Is there any other method to use those 2 variables without being in the loop? Or maybe to do not use a loop. I need a way to get the data from mysql.

Comment: I believe it has to be in a loop, these are MYSQL records. You don't know which will be returned first (if it's `website_register` or `website_offline`). So, just go with the `while` loop and just check what the value of `$name_system` is.

Comment: But I can't use the whole code in my every action.. for example I need to check if the $register_system == 1 in a form, am I suppose to write the whole code for that?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. You can just put this in your main core/include file and set constants using [define()](http://www.php.net/define). Something like: `define('SYSTEM_STATUS','offline');` Then, somewhere down your code, you can have: `if (SYSTEM_STATUS == 'offline') echo 'System is offline.';`

Comment: I need to get the data from mysql.. I want to make an admin control panel, from where to set if the site is online or offline.

Comment: And I have provided you good suggestions. You need to always call this function to check the status of your system. But don't write this code over and over again. Use functions or constants that will help you determine these values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the data to be available in multiple pages you need to store it somewhere.
SESSION if the data si small
SQLITE or a flat file if it is bigger
In situations like this you need to see how much memory and time each option uses and chose the one least expensive.

Answer (score 0):

use `$_SESSION` variables, like this:
wherever you got `$register_system`, it becomes `$_SESSION['register_system']`, and it can be accessed on the next page as `$_SESSION['register_system']`.

Similarly for `$offline_system`, it would be `$_SESSION['offline_system']` and accessed as `$_SESSION['offline_system']` on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this even simpler. If you are looking for specific values from the database you can just query for them and then assign the values.

e.g.

```
<?php

$registerResult = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT value FROM system WHERE name = 'website_register'"));
$offlineResult = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT value FROM system WHERE name = 'website_offline'"));

$registerSystem = ($registerResult[0] ? 1 : 0);
$offlineSystem  = ($offlineResult[0] ? 1 : 0);

?>
```